# How to reduce the spacing between labels and text in an inline description?

Tags: spacing, enumitem, description, inline

I'm using the option `inline` of the `enumitem` package to create lists inline. The numbered lists are perfects, however, the descriptions produces a lot of withe space between the label and the text.

[image]

How can I solve this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
    inline,     
    shortlabels     
]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Numerated:\par
%
\begin{enumerate*}
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate*}\par
%

Description\par
\begin{description*}
\item [First:] Text
\item [Second:] Text
\end{description*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `unboxed` mode:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[%
    inline,
    shortlabels
]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Numerated:\par
%
\begin{enumerate*}
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate*}\par
%

Description\par
\begin{description*}[itemjoin ={,\ }, mode=unboxed]
\item [First] Text
\item [Second] Text
\item [Third] Text
\end{description*}

\end{document}
```

[image]